# Using secured websocket in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, websocket

I'm using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) to implement websocket functionality in my MVC application. On the local setup I have https scheme with self signed certificate, whereas on production setup, I have paid certificate.

This is the syntax given in docs.

```
var server = new WebSocketServer("wss://0.0.0.0:8431");
server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("MyCert.pfx");
server.Start(socket =>
{
  //...use as normal
});
```

Here instead of `MyCert.pfx`, what should be given in case of self signed certificate / [aid certificate? Should it be a path? After providing only name, it gives error `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Comment: Yes, The parameter should be a file path, you can placed pfx file in AppData directory, And use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyCert.pfx")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you post it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: OK! Of cause, i already posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The parameter should be a file path, you can placed pfx file in AppData directory, And use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyCert.pfx")`